# Do I need a separate mutation for every delete?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

So I'm building a React/Apollo app, and I'm a bit stuck on deleting things.

In my Redux app, my 'delete' action just passes the object type and ID to my reducer, where I remove the object from my normalized state. This way, I can use the same 'delete' action/component/reducer for all objects. Neat!

In Apollo, I need to pick one query that references this object, and read/write to it in the `update` function, right? Like if I was deleting a `Person` I'd need to find some random query that includes `Persons` and use that?

Would it be bad practice to just have one query that gets *everything*, then remove the object from there? Or can I just remove it from wherever Apollo's normalizing everything to?

I think it kinda defeats the purpose of GraphQL to have a `GET_EVERYTHING` query that has every entity in it, but the alternative just sounds like a huge mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd typically have one delete mutation per type/node. Eg. deleteUser, deleteBook, deleteMessage, etc. The input for those mutations would typically be an ID, or a list of IDs if you want to be able to delete multiple entries at once.

You could also have a deleteNode mutation if you want to be able to delete any type of object with a single mutation. You should then make all deletable types inherit from a Node type - and make sure IDs are truly unique between all types.

Example with both delete mutations per entity and a general delete by node:

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}

type Person implements Node {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}

type Book implements Node {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  author: String!
}

union NodeEntity = Person | Book

type Query {
  person(id: ID!): Person
  persons: [Person!]! # You may want to limit the number of returned items

  # ... same thing for Book

  node(id: ID!): Node
  nodes: [Node!]! # You may want to limit the number of returned items
}

type Mutation {
  createPerson(input: CreatePersonInput!): CreatePersonPayload!
  updatePerson(input: UpdatePersonInput!): UpdatePersonPayload!
  deletePerson(input: DeletePersonInput!): DeletePersonPayload!

  # ... same thing for Book

  deleteNode(input: DeleteNodeInput!): DeleteNodePayload!

  # or simply:
  # deleteNode(id: String!): Boolean!
}

# Mutation inputs
input CreatePersonInput {
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}

input UpdatePersonInput {
  personId: ID!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}

input DeletePersonInput {
  personId: ID!
}

input DeleteNodeInput {
  nodeId: ID!
}

# Mutation results
type CreatePersonPayload {
  person: Person!
}

type UpdatePersonPayload {
  person: Person!
}

type DeletePersonPayload {
  person: Person!
}

type DeleteNodePayload {
  node: NodeEntity!

  # or simply:
  # node: Node
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I think in Apollo's case it may make the most sense to just have a different query for all of them. Cheers Mikael!